# Class with unsafe mutable pointer parameter of generic type decided by the initializer

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to create a class that operates differently based on its associated type. Apon initialization I will pass in a type to the initializer along with some other parameters not shown. My dilemma is  the following bit of code I want to write but can't due to a compiler error.

```
class Foo
{
    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
    var type: T.Type
    init?<T>(type: T.Type)
    {
        data = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
        self.type = type
    }

    func prepareForData()
    {
        data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(memoryAddress + variableOffset).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:1)
    }
}
```

where the class would be theoretically used like

`let thing = Foo(Int)` or `let thing2 = Foo(coolStruct)`

Is this even possible in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not check myself but the following should compile and work properly:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
    var type: T.Type
    init?(type: T.Type)
    {
        data = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>()
        self.type = type
    }

    func prepareForData()
    {
        data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(memoryAddress + variableOffset).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:1)
    }
}
```